# How can I drop the first level from a multi level column by chaining?

Tags: python, pandas

How can I drop the first level from a multi level column?

For a data frame:

```
tmp.head(1000).groupby(['user_id', 'aisle_id']).agg({'aisle_id': ['count']})
```

giving

```
                 aisle_id
                    count
user_id aisle_id         
382     38              1
        84              2
        115             1
3107    43              1
3321    37              1
        69              2
```

I want to drop the `aisle_id` in my columns. How can I do this by chaining commands without having to start another statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your groupby statement.

```
tmp.head(1000).groupby(['user_id', 'aisle_id'])['aisle_id'].agg(['count'])
```

Comment: That is indeed shorter. I didn't know I can use `[]` like that on a `DataFrameGroupBy` object ..

Answer (score 2):

You can quickly access the first level of the columns multiindex with the dot operator.  Similar to how you'd access columns with a single level index.

just add `.aisle_id` at the end.  Or equivalently `['aisle_id']`

```
tmp.head(1000).groupby(['user_id', 'aisle_id']).agg({'aisle_id': ['count']}) \
    .aisle_id

                  count
user_id aisle_id       
381     38            1
382     84            2
        115           1
3107    43            1
3321    37            1
        69            2
```

---

**Response to Comment**

@displayname these are equivalent `df.aisle_id` and `df.xs('aisle_id')`.  What I mean to point out is that it will access all columns whose first level is `aisle_id`.  If you were to aggregate the way you had, this will work identically to what ScottBoston has suggested.  The difference is that if you wanted to store the results of an aggregation into a variable that was over more that just one column, then those results are preserved and you can access just `aisle_id` with `df.aisle_id`.  The advantage of ScottBoston's solution is that when more that one column is available, we limit the calculation to just over `aisle_id`.

Comment: Nice solution if there's only one column. If there was another `mean` column e.g. then I'd have to got with Scotts version I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Use `reset_index` at level 0 with drop set to `True`.

```
tmp.head(1000).groupby(['user_id', 'aisle_id']) \
    .agg({'aisle_id': ['count']}).T.reset_index(level=0, drop=True).T
```

Comment: That worked. Although I had to transpose it additional 2 times and drop level 0 instead.